# How to generate .h header file using makefile and use it in same makefile for compilation of source?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I want to generate a header file abc.h using makefile.
And, include this header file in abc.cpp file, which has to be built from same makefile.

I am facing issue that it is not generating .h file before compiling .cpp file. So, i am getting an fatal error for header file not found.

e.g:

---

```
//abc.h
#define VAR "My Name"
```

---

```
//abc.cpp
#include "abc.h"
```

---

So, question is how to write makefile where it generates header file before compiling source file so that i don't get header file inclusion error?

I have created makefile like below but it's not generating file before any other compilation:

---

```
-include dummy

noinst_LTLIBRARIES = window.la

.PHONY: dummy

dummy:
    @echo "#define VAR "MYNAME" > abc.h

window_la_SOURCES = \
    ../src/abc.cpp 

window_la_CPPFLAGS = \
    -I $(srcdir)/../src/
```

---

I want to generate abc.h in above makefile before my compilation begins for abc.cpp. So, that i don't get fatal error for header inclusion. Please suggest.

Comment: Generate? It already exists. Is it in the same directory as `abc.cpp`?

Comment: Why do you want to generate the header? Why not handwrite it? Seems simple enough.

Comment: the easiest way is:  on the rule that is compiling (not linking) the abc.ccp file, add the header file: `abc.h` as a prerequisite.  Something like: `abc : abc.c abc.h`

Comment: The `gcc` compiler has a parameter that can be used to generate a (in this case) abc.d file, which also needs to be `#include` in the makefile and listed as a prerequisite on the rule for compiling the abc.c file.  However, all that will handle is the #include statements within the abc.c file.   If you want anything else such as any special #defines in the abc.h file, then you 'could' have an 'inline/hereis' file in the makefile that outputs the abc.h file  however, it would be far easier to just open your editor, gen the file, save it. Then the compile rule would list it as a prerequisite

Comment: If the abc.h file is not in the same directory (and even if it is in the same directory), adding a `-I.` (for the same directory) parameter to the compile command will tell the compiler where to find the header file

Comment: the posted abc.h file is missing certain key elements, like the wrapper that stops the file from being `#include`ed more than once

Comment: Yes. I can create header file by myself. But, requirement is to create header file from makefile and include that header file in source file which has to be build thru the same makefile.

Comment: It's more like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I would suggest use other way to do it instead of makefile.

Answer (score 5):

> how to write makefile where it generates header file before compiling source file so that i don't get header file inclusion error?

Here is a simple example (assuming that `abc.cpp` exists, compiles and has `main()`):

```
all: abc

abc.h: Makefile
        @echo "Generating $@"
        @echo "#define VAR \"MYNAME\"" > $@

abc.o: abc.h
abc.cpp: abc.h

abc: abc.o
```

By default build `abc`.

The target `abc.h` is generated by the shell script inside the `Makefile` and thus depends on the `Makefile`.

Tell `make` that the `abc.cpp` requires the `abc.h`.

Tell `make` that `abc.o` should be rebuild if `abc.h` changes.

Tell `make` to build the `abc` from the `abc.o`.

> Please suggest.

Code generation in the `GNU make`-based systems is hard and error prone. Though simple example as above seem trivial, on larger projects you might run into various problems for which `GNU make` offers literally no help in diagnosing or debugging.

My suggestion would be, unless you are prepared to read through the whole of [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html), is to avoid that.

Also, for the cases when you just need a preprocessor define, code generation is really an overkill: most IDEs and build systems already provide way to add preprocessor defines to the project. And many many things in the C/C++ could be reduced to the preprocessor defines.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. It's working fine for me now.

Answer (score 2):

Makefiles are a simple way to organize code compilation.

You have to create the header file yourself.

Comment: Not exactly true, but this is the simplest way to have the abc.h file

Comment: Yes. I can create header file by myself. But, requirement is to create header file from makefile and include that header file in source file which has to be build thru the same makefile.

Answer (score 0):

My answer includes also my particular problem, that I want to have in a .h file that is included by main.c the hash of the commit for which I am compiling.
This is the final version of it, working but only in Git Bash os CMD Line in Windows doesn't know the cut command.

```
tagver : ver prebuild postbuild
ver.h: Makefile
    @echo "Generating $@"
    @echo #ifndef INC_VER_H_ > inc\$@
    @echo #define INC_VER_H_ >> inc\$@

    $(eval GitTag_Major := $(shell git rev-parse --short=7 HEAD | cut -b 1))
    @echo "Defining major version to: $(GitTag_Major)"
    @echo #define MAJOR_NUMBER 0x$(GitTag_Major) >> inc\$@

    $(eval GitTag_minor := $(shell git rev-parse --short=7 HEAD | cut -b 2-3))
    @echo "Defining minor version to: $(GitTag_minor)"
    @echo #define MINOR_NUMBER 0x$(GitTag_minor) >> inc\$@

    $(eval GitTag_revision := $(shell git rev-parse --short=7 HEAD | cut -b 4-7))
    @echo "Defining revision version to: $(GitTag_revision)"
    @echo #define REVISION_NUMBER 0x$(GitTag_revision) >> inc\$@

    @echo #endif >> inc\$@
ver: ver.h
main.c: ver.h
```